# Why do I have lots of Hikari connections in waiting? How to troubleshoot?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, azure-sql-database, hikaricp

I have a lot of Hikari connections. We are obviously not using Hikari correctly but we don't know to find out where are these connections used exactly.

This is how my logs are looking like:

```
    30-01-2020 10:23:51.030 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.logPoolState - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=46)   
    30-01-2020 10:23:44.947 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.logPoolState - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=46)   
    30-01-2020 10:23:44.770 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.logPoolState - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=37)   
    30-01-2020 10:23:43.826 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.logPoolState - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=40)
```

How can we learn more about this? How to troubleshoot?

We have the setup with hibernate, k8s in azure with MS SQL server. We inherited this app :(

Comment: what's you hikari version?

Comment: we are using version 3.4.2

Comment: going through a very similar issue, but on AWS.. the same app on a static non-cloud server has limited WAITING connections. Did you happen to find answers @ddreian?